# Devops Artifact - Organization scoped feeds creation

Tags: devops, feed, artifacts

How can I create a new organization-scoped feed in Devops/Artifacts?

I could only create a new project-scoped feed, and couldn't find the option to make it organization-scoped...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to use a REST call to create an organization scoped feed, see:

Can No Longer Create Organization-scoped Feeds
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/859583/can-no-longer-create-organization-scoped-feeds.html

I'm wondering why there is no UI for this, maybe orga feeds are a bad practice?